# Is there a query for Netezza (Toad Data Point) for finding all tables where a specific field name exists

Tags: netezza, toad, datamart, field-names, toad-data-point

I have the following query which works perfectly when searching for tables that contain a specific field name that I am looking for in an Oracle database

however it does not work in Netezza (Data Mart) when using the Toad Data point tool. Can someone let me know if there is anything similar to the query below which would work in a Netezza Data Mart environment.

```
Select DISTINCT TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME
FROM ALL_TAB_COLUMNS
WHERE COLUMN NAME LIKE '%EXANOKE_FIELD_NAME%'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select DISTINCT TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME
FROM COLUMNS
WHERE COLUMN_NAME LIKE '%EXANOKE_FIELD_NAME%';